# How do I connect to an Intranet Site when I am not online?

Tags: networking, windows-explorer, hyper-v

I have a development machine with Hyper-V that is not connected to the Internet. On one of my virtual machines I am running SharePoint 2016, and I want to map my SharePoint site in Windows Explorer. When I click "Map Network Drive" and select "Connect to a website...", Windows tries to establish an Internet connection.

Connecting to the Internet even temporarily is NOT an option. Is this possible?

This is a Windows issue more than a SharePoint issue, that's why I am asking here.

Comment: Computers don't need to access the internet to map network drives, and you don't map connections to SharePoint using "connect to a website".

Comment: Actually, you can. I have done it many times. You enter the URL of the SharePoint site, and you have access through Windows Explorer to the Lists and Libraries of your site.

Comment: I am not mapping to a network drive, but that is the wizard you use to connect to a website. As soon as I click "Connect to a website", I am prompted to create an Internet connection.

Comment: Open one of the SP libraries in IE and in the toolbar should be an option to view it I think file explorer.